# Mysql Indent columns

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
select * from Vulnerabilities;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+------+
| CVE           | Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | Date       | Score | Type |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+------+
| CVE-2014-9364 | Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in the Unified Login form in the LoginToboggan module 7.x-1.x before 7.x-1.4 for Drupal allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via unspecified vectors.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 2014-12-10 |     4 | XSS  |
| CVE-2014-9365 | The HTTP clients in the (1) httplib, (2) urllib, (3) urllib2, and (4) xmlrpclib libraries in CPython (aka Python) 2.x before 2.7.9 and 3.x before 3.4.3, when accessing an HTTPS URL, do not (a) check the certificate against a trust store or verify that the server hostname matches a domain name in the subject&amp;#039;s (b) Common Name or (c) subjectAltName field of the X.509 certificate, which allows man-in-the-middle attackers to spoof SSL servers via an arbitrary valid certificate. | 2014-12-12 |     6 | XSS  |
```

And as u see, unless you have a 200" Display it's unreadable I would like it to have a readable format, I guess my introducing a /n in Description text every X size.

I hope I made myself clear although the way I described it is not the best... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have to do this in the CLI?

Comment: Yes, I have to do this in the CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, that you need this for a better working experience when using the command line tool, then there are various solutions.

Instead of using `;` as delimiter, you can use `\G`. The difference is this:

```
mysql > select 1, 2, 3;
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql > select 1, 2, 3\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another possibility is to set a different pager. When working on Linux, you can use for example `less`.

```
mysql > pager less -SFX
PAGER set to 'less -SFX'
```

When the result fits on the screen, there's no difference. If not, you can scroll up/down/sideways with arrow keys.

To turn this off again, just do

```
mysql > pager
Default pager wasn't set, using stdout.
```

Comment: The \G helps, but what if I want to keep the format, with the column Description shorter? I mean more lines and shorter

Comment: Do you mean, you want to cut the column off or wrap it around?

Comment: I guess wrap it around, I want a clear format when the text is too long.

I want to keep the name of the columns in one line and below the text, and if some column text is very long, dividing it into different lines keeping the format

Comment: Then the pager thing is what you're looking for. Have a look at the `less` options. There's no other built-in functionality in the mysql command line tool, that does what you're looking for.

Comment: Less is ok but if one field is too long I have to move with the keys to see the other fields.

I want to divide a long field into several lines ! To see all at a glance

Comment: Yes, like I said, have a look at less. I won't do all the work. I usually use the `-S` option, which says `Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded.  That is, the portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default is to fold long lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.` So you don't want to use this option. I don't know however, how you can specify the screen width. Finding that out is up to you.